# What is the best way to access configuration data in a .NET Core worker service/console app?

Tags: .net-core, .net-6.0, configurationmanager, worker-service

I have a series of .NET Core worker services (targeting .NET 6). I am accessing configuration data from `appsettings.json` through `hostcontext` and that works fine:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    // Start the application
    await CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().RunAsync();
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseWindowsService()
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            // I can access config data like this:
            var connectionString = hostcontext.Configuration["ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString"];
        });
```

However, I now need to get configuration data from within `Main()` before `CreateHostBuilder()` is called.

I can do something like this, but is there a better way? It feels wrong to build a `ConfigurationBuilder` just to grab this one value, is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    // Get the configuration
    var environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production";

    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", true, true);

    var configuration = builder.Build();

    // Start the application
    await CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().RunAsync();
}
```

Comment: Why do you need it early? Can you use a background service or singleton instead?

Comment: It's for a logger configuration...I am switching my Serilog to log to a SQL DB in addition to the flat files it currently generates, and I wanted the cxn string to be pulled from the config. Because I'm logging any exceptions on app start, I have to grab that cxn string before the app starts...

PS: Your articles on async have taught me so much! I truly appreciate all of the effort you've spent educating people like me! :)

Comment: Using a separate config builder is the best way I know of.